# setting canShowCallOut = NO for current location annotation, iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotation, currentlocation

I am using custom call out (title and subtitle)for Current location icon. I tried following to disable default annotation but it does not work.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *userLocationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
        userLocationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        NSLog(@"[annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]");
        return nil;
    }

}
```

Only way it works is

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)ann
{
    if([ann.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] )
    {
       [mymap deselectAnnotation:ann.annotation animated:NO];
    }
}
```

But it lags sometimes. Is there other way do disable default callout view for current location annotation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the blue point by default annotation for current  location?

Comment: @Ravin, Yes. By Current location annotation I mean blue pulsating dot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get this done one need to get reference of current location `MKAnnotationView`. One can get this reference anywhere but it is better to get it as soon as user location is determined.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
{
 MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];
annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

}
```

Or use following method

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
MKAnnotationView *aV; 
     for (aV in views) {
            if ([aV.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
                MKAnnotationView* annotationView = aV;
                 annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

            }
    }
```

and if want to change in canShowCallout property in runtime then one can use following

```
for (AnnotationClass* annotation in mapView.annotations) 
    {
        if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] )
        {
             MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
             annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found that the middle solution is not correct, because you iterate on views, therefore the class will be `MKUserLocationView` instead of `MKUserLocation`, which seems to be a private class. I recommend you to compare the inverse: you shall turn off `canShowCallout` when the annotation's class is NOT your own annotation's class (`MKAnnotation` for example).

Comment: This has stopped working in iOS7; the workaround (which also supports earlier versions) is to set `userLocation.title = @"";` in the method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation`  Setting the title to an empty string prevents the callout from appearing.

Comment: None of these methods worked well for me on iOS 7. The callout was disabled, but the blue dot was still selectable - you can tell if it overlaps with another map annotation.

Answer (score 6):

an update to this, using swift (based on chatur's answer):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didAddAnnotationViews views: [MKAnnotationView]!) {

    for view in views {
        if view.annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
            view.canShowCallout = false
        }
    }

}
```

**Note: using this, i did not require anything else to make it work**

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

This worked for me: Just add this delegate method.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for var view in views {
        view.canShowCallout = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Swift 3.0 / iOS 10.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    (views.filter { $0.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) }).first?.canShowCallout = false
}
```

Rather than loop through all the views, I just rely on the `filter` command, followed by the optional call on first since there should only be one location, and then set the value to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Objective-C

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
        MKAnnotationView *userLocationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];   
        userLocationView.canShowCallout = NO;
}  

// Swift 4.2

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        let userAnnotationView = mapView.view(for: userLocation)
        userAnnotationView?.canShowCallout = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Sorry for getting you wrong.

I banged my head on this.

This is the only way i have succeeded doing it. the problem with this method is that you have to change the UserLocation view. So it might be not so user friendly.

Any way:

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation                                                                           reuseIdentifier:nil];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-icon.png"];
        annotationView.enabled=NO;
         return annotationView;
    };
     ........}
```

Have to run to the kindergarden to take my kid :)

Good luck

Comment: I just read your EDIT and thanks for your time. But in this way I will loose the accuracy animation of blue dot. If I find any better way I will let you know.

Comment: please see the answer posted by me.