# Changing Google Maps current location blue dot color iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, location

I am trying to customize blue dot which represents current location in Google Maps.
I am trying to change its color or use custom image as icon. image.

I checked

[Customize Google Maps blue dot for current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331086/customize-google-maps-blue-dot-for-current-location)

But i want to enable location as well and also i does not fit image exactly on top of blue dot (though i use exact coordinates).

I tried to put circle on top of Map using

```
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
 radius:50];
 circ.map = mapView_;
 circ.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But it sits behind blue dot.

Comment: have tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442832/setting-canshowcallout-no-for-current-location-annotation-iphone 1st answer

Comment: Thanks but i am using Google Maps not Mapkit :)

Comment: @Mann did yu find the solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced same problem and I've used UIImageView, placing it's center at user location and added it to MapView. Also I am changing its center in "didupdatelocation" delegate method everytime with some animation.

GMSCircle will add inside map. I guess thats why its not worked. You need to add UIImageView on top of map say

```
[myMap addsubview:YourImageView]
```

It's working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this

```
 CLLocationDegrees degrees = 90;
 circ.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
 circ.rotation = degrees;
```